# preventDefault for keyboard events in angular

Tags: angular

I use the following code to listen for up and down arrow in my code

```
 @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
    keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.DOWN_ARROW) {
            if (!this.isOpen) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.keyboardRowChange(1);
            } 
        }
        if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.UP_ARROW) {
            if (!this.isOpen) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.keyboardRowChange(-1);        
            }  
        }
    }
```

Basically I use it to change rows on a table along as a modal is not open. The issue is that the window also scrolls with up or down arrow. Generally `preventDefault()` would accomplish this but even with `preventDefault()` the window scrolls with up and down arrow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't the window usually scroll on keydown, not keyup?

Comment: I'm not sure, are you saying that I need to listen for a keydown event and prevent default in that scenario?

Comment: That's my guess.The event object angular is giving you is the same as the one in a typical listener.

Comment: wait yes you're right, I never really understood the differences between the various key events, just looked it up, that solved my problem.

Comment: I actually want to keep the movement of the rows bound to keyup so the user can't hold down and jump rows very quickly. I'm creating another listener, for the keydown to prevent that action.